# Python subprocess.call seems to ignore parameters

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have written two small functions in Python to call `mysqldump` and `mysql` from console, so I am able to create a database backup and then restore it:

```
# Makes a backup current database status
def backupDatabase():
    if(os.path.exists('myDatabaseBackup.sql')):
        os.remove('myDatabaseBackup.sql')
    call(['mysqldump', '-u myUsername myDatabase > myDatabaseBackup.sql'])


# Restores database
def restoreDatabase():
    call(['mysql', '-u myUsername myDatabase < myDatabaseBackup.sql'])
```

Nevertheless, they are not working. I have read that call gets two values: the executable and the parameters, but it looks that parameters are being ignored, since the output after calling backupDatabase is:

> Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR ... For more options,
>   se mysqldump --help

What's wrong? I know I could use `Pipes` (I don't know how at the moment, just know they exist and are an alternative), but since this looks like a pretty simple task I guess `subprocess.call` should be enough. So, is it possible to fix this with `subprocess.call`? (If not, please provide some help for `Pipes` or any other solution).

Also, I'm using `MySQLdb` package for other purposes, so if it is possible to backup and restore somehow using this package, it would be great.

Comment: Some guesses: 1) You must split the arguments, otherwise they end up quoted. '-u', 'myUsername', 'myDataBase'. 2) <, > is shell syntax that's not interprete by default. try with shell=True. (and split accordingly so it's not interpreted as a single argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `subprocess.call` expects you to pass each command line parameter separately, like this:

```
subprocess.call(['mysqldump', '-u', 'myUsername'])
```

Second, to redirect the output, you pass additional `stdout` argument, which, among other things, can be an open file object:

```
with open('myDatabaseBackup.sql', 'w') as fout:
    subprocess.call(['mysqldump', '-u', 'myUsername'], stdout=fout)
```

(For the second redirection you naturally use `stdin`. More details are in [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments))

Answer (score 1):

Redirection operators `<` and `>` are processed by the shell. If there's no shell, they won't work.

Try passing `shell=True` to [`call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
call(['mysqldump', '-u myUsername myDatabase > myDatabaseBackup.sql'], shell=True)
call(['mysql', '-u myUsername myDatabase < myDatabaseBackup.sql'], shell=True)
```